# Optimising a forward index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I am building a forward index on a wiki using MySQL.  I am running into performance problems with queries and I am hoping for some help optimising either my schema or my queries

The database is around 1GB and it has three tables

- fi_page is the table of 800k wiki pages
- fi_keyword is a table of 70k keywords

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `fi_keyword` (  
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
    UNIQUE KEY `keyword` (`keyword`)  
  );
  ```
- fi_titlekeywordlink is a table with 6 million entries linking keywords to wiki pages

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `fi_titlekeywordlink` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `keyword_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fi_titlekeywordlink_a6434082` (`keyword_id`),
    KEY `fi_titlekeywordlink_c2d3d2bb` (`page_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `keyword_id_refs_id_67197756` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_id`) REFERENCES `fi_keyword` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `paper_id_refs_id_705ddf03` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `fi_page` (`id`)
  );
  ```

I am translating up a search for 'search terms galore' into an sql query such as

```
    select p.*
      from
        fi_keyword as k0, fi_titlekeywordlink as l0,
        fi_keyword as k1, fi_titlekeywordlink as l1,
        fi_keyword as k2, fi_titlekeywordlink as l2,
        fi_keyword as k3, fi_titlekeywordlink as l3,
        fi_page as p
      where
        k0.keyword = e and k0.id = l0.keyword_id and p.id = l0.paper_id
        and k1.keyword = 'search' and k1.id = l1.keyword_id and p.id = l1.paper_id
        and k2.keyword = 'terms' and k2.id = l2.keyword_id and p.id = l2.paper_id
        and k3.keyword = 'galore' and k3.id = l3.keyword_id and p.id = l3.paper_id
      limit 1,10
```

however this is taking around half a second to run on my MBP.  Do you have any suggestions on how to speed up this sort of operation either by changing the schema or the query?  I cannot use a separate search server in this case, the forward index must run on MySQL.  Thank you.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes, but I am happy to change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the cost of insertion performance, you could delete the surrogate `id` primary key columns from both tables and make your primary key index on the `keyword` column for fi_keyword and (`keyword_id`, `page_id`) as the primary key index for fi_titlekeywordlink.

If you are using InnoDB, primary keys are clustered indexes, so they are much faster.

Even if you don't make this change, a compound (multi-column) index of (`keyword_id`, `page_id`) on fi_titlekeywordlink would improve performance because you would have a covering index (MySQL wouldn't have to visit the table data) on fi_titlekeywordlink. This assumes that your MySQL server has enough RAM to fit all indexes in memory and that you've configured MySQL server to allow it to use enough RAM to make it so (configuration variables differ between [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) and [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size)).

Sometimes, an implicit JOIN can get too complex for MySQL to properly optimize. You should also consider rewriting the query with explicit ANSI standard joins using `JOIN` and `ON`.

You probably just wrote `SELECT p.*` for brevity, but be sure to only select the columns that you require so that you're not returning unneeded data. Only returning the columns that you need reduces the work load.

Also, the first row in a LIMIT clause is 0, so `LIMIT 1, 10` skips the first row. Use `LIMIT 0, 10` to get the first 10 rows.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will work through these suggestions.

Comment: I've added a compound index and swapped to ansi join syntax, that has helped a great deal.  It is taking a little longer to figure out how to change the primary keys, but I will do that too.  Thanks for your help.